# How can I initialize an at::Scalar?

Tags: c++, pytorch, libtorch

I was trying to invoke a PyTorch C++ API function called *linspace*. When I tried to write it like Python style, I wrote:

```
torch::Tensor x = torch::linspace(-1, 1, 100);
```

and this code got a segmentation fault:

```
[1]    6038 segmentation fault  ./example-app
```

I read the C++ docs in pytorch.org, and it gave the format of linspace:

```
at::Tensor torch::linspace(const at::Scalar &start, const at::Scalar &end, c10::optional<int64_t> steps = c10::nullopt, at::TensorOptions options = {})
```

Here I didn't know what exactly *at::Scalar* means, so I searched it in the docs about *at* namespace, but I didn't find any class called *Scalar*.

However, I did find many functions in the *at* namespace that have a parameter of *Scalar* type.

This is the docs about [*linspace*](https://pytorch.org/cppdocs/api/function_namespacetorch_1a69dd7568317a438c3e894a78dffb9ab5.html#exhale-function-namespacetorch-1a69dd7568317a438c3e894a78dffb9ab5) function, and this is the docs about [*at*](https://pytorch.org/cppdocs/api/namespace_at.html#namespace-at) namespace.

Comment: Are you sure you're using the same library as the docs you're looking at? The third argument is an `optional`, which should not be implicitly convertible from `int`, so this should be a compile error based on that signature alone, not a segfault at runtime

Comment: The one line of code you posted here has no problem, it is a perfectly fine use of `linspace`. The segfault must come from somewhere else

Answer (score 0):

I met another scalar-related issue today and started looking for documentation. I couldn't find documentation but found this in a header file:

```
namespace c10
{

/**
 * Scalar represents a 0-dimensional tensor which contains a single element.
 * Unlike a tensor, numeric literals (in C++) are implicitly convertible to
 * Scalar (which is why, for example, we provide both add(Tensor) and
 * add(Scalar) overloads for many operations). It may also be used in
 * circumstances where you statically know a tensor is 0-dim and single size,
 * but don't know its type.
 */
class C10_API Scalar
{
 public:
  Scalar() : Scalar(int64_t(0)) {}

  void destroy()
  {
    if (Tag::HAS_si == tag || Tag::HAS_sd == tag) {
      raw::intrusive_ptr::decref(v.p);
      v.p = nullptr;
    }
  }
  ...    
  Scalar(T vv) : tag(Tag::HAS_b)
  {
    v.i = convert<int64_t, bool>(vv);
  }
  ...
}
```

It wasn't hard to find, but I think they should have put it in the main documentation... In any case, it looks like you did it right.